# Dirac Lagrangian under charge conjugation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, charge-conjugation

I am trying to understand why the Dirac Lagrangian is invariant under charge conjugation.

The Dirac Lagrangian is:

$$\mathcal{L} = i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi - m \bar{\psi}\psi $$

I know that under charge conjugation the flowing formulas are correct:

$$
\hat{C} \, \bar{\psi}\psi \, \hat{C} = +\bar{\psi}\psi, \\
\hat{C} \, \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi \,\hat{C} = -\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi, \\
\hat{C} \, \partial_\mu \,\hat{C} = \partial_\mu \\
$$

Therefore:

$$
\hat{C} \, \mathcal{L} \,\hat{C} = \hat{C} \, i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi \,\hat{C}  - \hat{C} \, m \bar{\psi}\psi  \,\hat{C} 
$$
Where
$$
\hat{C} \, i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi \,\hat{C} = i\hat{C} \, \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \hat{C} \hat{C} \,\partial_\mu\psi \,\hat{C}   = i\hat{C} \, \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \hat{C} \partial_\mu \hat{C} \,\psi \,\hat{C}
$$

And because $\partial_\mu$ commutes with all $\gamma^\mu$ we use the same calculations as in $\hat{C} \, \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi \,\hat{C} = -\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$ and get:

$$\hat{C} \, i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi \,\hat{C} = -i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi$$

Therefore overall:

$$
\hat{C} \, \mathcal{L} \,\hat{C} = -i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu\psi - m \bar{\psi}\psi \neq \mathcal{L}
$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that charge conjugation interchanges the anticommuting $\bar \psi$ and  $\psi$, so after conjugation by $\hat C$ the $\partial_\mu$ acts on the $\bar\psi$, and needs a sign-changing integration by parts.

In detail:
$$
\hat C \psi \hat C^{-1}= {\mathcal C}^{-1}\bar\psi^T\\
  \hat C \bar \psi \hat C^{-1}  = - \psi^T {\mathcal C}
$$
where the ${\mathcal C}$ matrix obeys
$$
{\mathcal C}\gamma^\mu  {\mathcal C}^{-1}= -(\gamma^\mu)^T. 
$$

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the integration by parts